# Is there any good gem to bookmark record of particular model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have 3 models such as User model,Book model, and Author model.

I'd like to implement the function with which, User can bookmark record of Books or Authors as
their favorite.

Is there any good gem to do this easily???

I'm not thinking of making on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `acts_as_votable` [gem](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) and use the likes as the bookmarks.

You could use

`@user.get_up_voted Book`

This will return all books that `@user` has voted up (these are the bookmarks of this user)

you will find more information in the voter section [here](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#the-voter).

Comment: how do you use it as the bookmarks? Can you show me an example please?? For example, when you are loading the page that show the list of books you added to favorite list.

Comment: I added an example in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use either awesome_nested_set gem or acts_as_votable gem. It will may be useful for you. May solve all your requirements.

Check this below link 
[awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set)
or [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)